# VIM defaults.vim not working as expected; some commands only working from home dir

Tags: vim, raspbian

System: Raspberry pi running Raspbian Stretch, fully updated.

Here is my entire ~/.vimrc code. Emphasis on the bottom line, which is what I use to verify that I am loading the correct VIMRC file. Everything in this VIMRC works as I would expect when I run vim as my user.

```
" All system-wide defaults are set in $VIMRUNTIME/debian.vim (usually just
" /usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/debian.vim) and sourced by the call to :runtime
" you can find below.  If you wish to change any of those settings, you should
" do it in this file (/etc/vim/vimrc), since debian.vim will be overwritten
" everytime an upgrade of the vim packages is performed.  It is recommended to
" make changes after sourcing debian.vim since it alters the value of the
" 'compatible' option.

" This line should not be removed as it ensures that various options are
" properly set to work with the Vim-related packages available in Debian.
runtime! debian.vim

" Uncomment the next line to make Vim more Vi-compatible
" NOTE: debian.vim sets 'nocompatible'.  Setting 'compatible' changes numerous
" options, so any other options should be set AFTER setting 'compatible'.
"set compatible

" Vim5 and later versions support syntax highlighting. Uncommenting the next
" line enables syntax highlighting by default.
"syntax on

" If using a dark background within the editing area and syntax highlighting
" turn on this option as well
set background=dark

" Uncomment the following to have Vim jump to the last position when
" reopening a file
if has("autocmd")
  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
endif

" Uncomment the following to have Vim load indentation rules and plugins
" according to the detected filetype.
"if has("autocmd")
"  filetype plugin indent on
"endif

" The following are commented out as they cause vim to behave a lot
" differently from regular Vi. They are highly recommended though.
"set showcmd            " Show (partial) command in status line.
"set showmatch          " Show matching brackets.
"set ignorecase         " Do case insensitive matching
"set smartcase          " Do smart case matching
"set incsearch          " Incremental search
"set autowrite          " Automatically save before commands like :next and :make
"set hidden             " Hide buffers when they are abandoned
"set mouse=a            " Enable mouse usage (all modes)

" Source a global configuration file if available
if filereadable("/etc/vim/vimrc.local")
  source /etc/vim/vimrc.local
endif

syntax on

set mouse-=a

set backspace=indent,eol,start

echo "home vimrc loaded"
```

HOWEVER, when I either remove my copy of ~/.vimrc, or (more importantly since it's the issue I'm experiencing), if I run sudo vim, my global default version of vimrc (/usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim, which is hardlinked to /etc/vim/vimrc) does not work as expected. In particular, the following 2 issues I notice:

-set mouse-=a appears to work even when the line is commented out.

-set backspace=indent,eol,start does not work.

It DOES echo that I am loading the global vimrc, and the echo is modified accordingly if I edit it.

Here is my global vimrc file.

```
" All system-wide defaults are set in $VIMRUNTIME/debian.vim (usually just
" /usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/debian.vim) and sourced by the call to :runtime
" you can find below.  If you wish to change any of those settings, you should
" do it in this file (/etc/vim/vimrc), since debian.vim will be overwritten
" everytime an upgrade of the vim packages is performed.  It is recommended to
" make changes after sourcing debian.vim since it alters the value of the
" 'compatible' option.

" This line should not be removed as it ensures that various options are
" properly set to work with the Vim-related packages available in Debian.
runtime! debian.vim

" Uncomment the next line to make Vim more Vi-compatible
" NOTE: debian.vim sets 'nocompatible'.  Setting 'compatible' changes numerous
" options, so any other options should be set AFTER setting 'compatible'.
"set compatible

" Vim5 and later versions support syntax highlighting. Uncommenting the next
" line enables syntax highlighting by default.
"syntax on

" If using a dark background within the editing area and syntax highlighting
" turn on this option as well
set background=dark

" Uncomment the following to have Vim jump to the last position when
" reopening a file
if has("autocmd")
  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
endif

" Uncomment the following to have Vim load indentation rules and plugins
" according to the detected filetype.
"if has("autocmd")
"  filetype plugin indent on
"endif

" The following are commented out as they cause vim to behave a lot
" differently from regular Vi. They are highly recommended though.
"set showcmd            " Show (partial) command in status line.
"set showmatch          " Show matching brackets.
"set ignorecase         " Do case insensitive matching
"set smartcase          " Do smart case matching
"set incsearch          " Incremental search
"set autowrite          " Automatically save before commands like :next and :make
"set hidden             " Hide buffers when they are abandoned
"set mouse=a            " Enable mouse usage (all modes)

" Source a global configuration file if available
if filereadable("/etc/vim/vimrc.local")
  source /etc/vim/vimrc.local
endif

syntax on

set mouse-=a

set backspace=indent,eol,start

echo "global vimrc loaded"
```

I feel like I must be having a misunderstanding of how the vimrc defaults works. Any help appreciated.

EDIT WITH MORE INFO:

When I create a file /root/.vimrc and then run sudo vim, it does properly use that vimrc, and everything works as it should when running as root. Global file still doesn't work when I remove my local vimrc though. So it's definitely nothing with user permissions. Is there a second vim file besides vimrc that could be an issue?

EDIT2:

Output of :version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Sep 30 2017 18:21:38)
Included patches: 1-197, 322, 377-378, 550, 703, 706-707
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             -clipboard       +dialog_con      +file_in_path    +job             -lua             +mouse_sgr       +path_extra      +rightleft       +tag_old_static  +user_commands   +writebackup
+arabic          +cmdline_compl   +diff            +find_in_path    +jumplist        +menu            -mouse_sysmouse  -perl            -ruby            -tag_any_white   +vertsplit       -X11
+autocmd         +cmdline_hist    +digraphs        +float           +keymap          +mksession       +mouse_urxvt     +persistent_undo +scrollbind      -tcl             +virtualedit     -xfontset
-balloon_eval    +cmdline_info    -dnd             +folding         +lambda          +modify_fname    +mouse_xterm     +postscript      +signs           +termguicolors   +visual          -xim
-browse          +comments        -ebcdic          -footer          +langmap         +mouse           +multi_byte      +printer         +smartindent     +terminfo        +visualextra     -xpm
++builtin_terms  +conceal         +emacs_tags      +fork()          +libcall         -mouseshape      +multi_lang      +profile         +startuptime     +termresponse    +viminfo         -xsmp
+byte_offset     +cryptv          +eval            +gettext         +linebreak       +mouse_dec       -mzscheme        -python          +statusline      +textobjects     +vreplace        -xterm_clipboard
+channel         +cscope          +ex_extra        -hangul_input    +lispindent      +mouse_gpm       +netbeans_intg   -python3         -sun_workshop    +timers          +wildignore      -xterm_save
+cindent         +cursorbind      +extra_search    +iconv           +listcmds        -mouse_jsbterm   +num64           +quickfix        +syntax          +title           +wildmenu
-clientserver    +cursorshape     +farsi           +insert_expand   +localmap        +mouse_netterm   +packages        +reltime         +tag_binary      -toolbar         +windows
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vim-UkjqTY/vim-8.0.0197=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SO
URCE=1
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl
```

Output of :scriptnames

```
1: /usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/gzip.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/logiPat.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/manpager.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/vim.vim
```

Comment: What is the full output of `:version`? What is the full output of `:scriptnames`? Did you know about `$ sudo -e`?

Comment: romainl, I have edited the original post with the outputs.

I believe sudo -e would accomplish something similar as sudoedit, where it maintains my settings? If so, I am aware of that option and will probably use it long-term, was just hoping to understand why defaults.vim isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` (expanding to `/usr/share/vim/vim80/runtime/defaults.vim`) **isn't** your global vimrc (unless raspbian sets it up differently). Normally on a debian system `/etc/vim/vimrc` is hardlinked to `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`, which is the default *system* vimrc file. This file *always* gets sourced regardless of who you are (see `:h system-vimrc`). `defaults.vim` is a special file with weird behaviour; from `:h defaults`

```
If Vim is started normally and no user vimrc file is found, the $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
script is loaded.  This will set 'compatible' off, switch on syntax highlighting and 
a few more things.
```

So `defaults.vim` will be sourced for every user that doesn't have their own vimrc, and it sets `mouse=a` amongst other things. This is why creating `/root/.vimrc` made things work as expected.

I would recommend not changing `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` or `defaults.vim`, because both those files will be overwritten when vim updates. If you want to use your vimrc as root then you could use something like `sudoedit` instead of logging into root, or start vim from root with something like `vim -u /path/to/my/vimrc`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply flemingfleming.

/usr/share/vim/ does not have a vimrc file inside of it; only 3 folders, addons, registry, and vim80, none of which appear to have a vimrc inside of them either. It is definitely loading from defaults.vim, as when I edit my echo statement, it gets reflected when I re-load vim from a user without a ~/.vimrc.

I was aware of sudoedit, and will probably use that for my long-term solution, but was hoping to gain some knowledge on why defaults.vim is not working as I expected.

Comment: It's expected that `defaults.vim` will be loaded when a user doesn't have a vimrc, that's what it's for. I guess rasbian is set up a bit differently to debain, locically I'd expect  `/etc/vim/vimrc` to be sourced. You could check where `$VIM/vimrc` points to, and have a look at `:h .vimrc`, which lays out clearly the full initialisation order to see if there's anything else you might take note of.